# Increasing variance in random numbers generated by random.randint() in python

Tags: python, random, variance

I'm generating a list of random numbers using randint() in random. I've observed that the variance in the numbers generated in not very high for a high range. How do I introduce maximum variance in the numbers after generating them ?

Comment: You shouldn't; as it says in a [**warning** here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), "The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator." There's another [million and one generators here](https://pypi.org/search/?q=random).

Comment: Actually I want to use these highly varied numbers as an input to time.sleep() to randomly introduce pauses in my python script which I'm using for crawling websites.

Comment: Well, simply doubling each output of `randint()` would quadruple the variance of your sample, so I doubt that maximising the variance is actually what you want. Or maybe you have some other constraints? Do you mean "variance" in the usual statistical sense? If not, what _do_ you mean by variance in this context? It's hard to tell what you're really asking here.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thanks.